# Trabalhando com Imagens - PHP

Tags: php, imagem, gd

Já trabalhei e ainda trabalho com algumas bibliotecas de manipulação de imagens em `PHP`, porém resolvi estudar na origem as manipulações, como funcionam, como implementar e trabalhar com as imagens.

> Como sabemos as imagens são subidas através de um `<input type="file">`, o que permite subir qualquer tipo de arquivo, já estou considerando as alterações no `HTML` e/ou `JavaScript`, que podem ser feitas pelo usuário mal intencionado.

Já tenho um certo tratamento através dos erros nativos do `$_FILE['image']['error']`, também usando `getimagesize()` para, de certa forma, confirmar a veracidade da imagem, usando `$_FILE['image']['type']`, usando `MIME` e offset `2` retirado do próprio `getimagesize()`, que fica assim:

```
//array de arquivos suportados
$support=array(1=>"image/gif",2=>"image/jpg",3=>"image/png");

//informações do getimagesize()
$getimagesize=getimagesize($_FILE['image']['tmp_name']);

//uma das verificações
if($support[$getimagesize[2]]==$getimagesize['mime']){}
```

Por que esse tipo de verificação? Porque existem formas de criar arquivos que não são imagens com extensões de uma, e além desse exemplo, também faço uma verificação baseada nos tamanhos `imagesx` e `imagesy`, para tentar prevenir ao máximo possíveis arquivos maliciosos.

Então, durante esse estudo, me deparei com algumas questões nas quais eu ainda não encontrei nada na internet que sanassem as minhas duvidas, são elas:

- Quais os erros, obtidos pelo `$_FILES['image']['error']` que ainda mantém o arquivo no servidor?

*Por exemplo, subir um arquivo `.txt` que não é uma imagem, mas é um arquivo completo, gera o `$_FILES['image']['error'] == 0`, então o arquivo foi transferido para a pasta temporária e consigo excluí-la.*

---

O retorno da função `getimagesize()` é um array contendo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 500
    [1] => 300
    [2] => 3
    [3] => width="500" height="300"
    [bits] => 8
    [mime] => image/png
)
```

- Qual é a finalidade da chave `bits` e qual seus valores, mínimo, máximo?

> **Obs:** Sei que é minha primeira pergunta e pode estar um pouco confusa, mas tentei ser o mais claro possível, se alguém puder me ajudar ficarei grato.

Comment: A chave bits só informa a quantidade de bits que a imagem tem por cor. No seu caso aí, é um PNG de 8 bits. Poderia ser um JPEG de 24 bits, ou talvez um PNG de 24 bits.

Comment: Obrigado @sam, e esses valores que você citou são valores padrão?

Comment: Não sou expert em imagens, mas acho que pode variar. Por exemplo, um GIF tem 8 bits (256 cores), já JPG e PNG podem ter 24 bits (16 milhões de cores). Mas o importante é que a chave "bits" apenas informa os bits por cor da imagem.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 0):

> Quais os erros, obtidos pelo $_FILES['image']['error'] que ainda mantém o arquivo no servidor?

Somente quando o valor da chave `'error'` for 0 (ou a constante `UPLOAD_ERR_OK`) o arquivo será mantido em `'tmp_name'`

> Qual é a finalidade da chave bits de `getimagesize()` e qual seus valores, mínimo, máximo?

A chave bits informa a quantidade de bits que a imagem tem por cor. No exemplo é um PNG de 8 bits. Poderia ser um JPEG ou PNG de 24 bits. (créditos a [@Sam](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8063/sam))